# how to solve the equation $sg’(s) + g(s) = ag(ks)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions, recreational-mathematics, functional-equations

What function g satisfies the equation

$$sg’(s) + g(s) = ag(ks)$$

Where a and k are constants and s(the variable) is real number.

Comment: Just continuous? Does $g'$ not refer to the derivative of $g$?

Comment: Thank you for the notification. I’ve updated it. Yes, g’ refers to the derivative of g

Comment: Also what have you tried? Have you considered applying the Laplace transform or Frobenius method?

Comment: Sorry, I’m a high school student and I’m doing this of personal interest. So I haven’t yet learnt about Laplace transform or Frobenius method. Is that the only way? I will read it up though

Comment: Is there any particular reason you are asking about this equation? Does it appear in some context? For example, mentioning [your previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3596047/272831).

Comment: Yes actually, I was trying to solve the equation       f’(x)=kf(x-1)

Comment: Yes, it does come from the previous post but it was closed to I reposted it differently. The original equation was f’(x)=kf(x-1) but I worked it down to the previous post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105986/discussion-between-david-okogbenin-and-simply-beautiful-art).

Comment: If $k$ is positive, then write $f(x)=g(e^x)$ and notice that this function satisfies the delay differential equation $$ f'(x) + f(x) = a f(x+\log k). $$ A solution may be found by assuming that $f$ takes the form $f(x) = ce^{rx}$ and determining the value of $r$.